# How to get output of console.log when using node:test?

Tags: node.js, node-test-runner

I am using [`node:test`](https://nodejs.org/api/test.html) test runner.

The test simply prints to stdout using `console.log`.

```js
console.log({ foo: JSON.stringify(choices) });
```

I expect the output to include the result of `JSON.stringify`, but instead I am getting:

```bash
node --test --test-reporter=spec src/createChat.test.ts
ℹ {
ℹ foo:
ℹ }
```

Comment: What's in `choices`?